# Getting the real appdata folder under Desktop Bridge

Tags: wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I've got a WPF app that writes data to %appdata%. I understand the writes get redirected to a per-app location, but I want to have a menu option in my app to open the folder with the app data. As far as the app is concerned, it's writing to C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\VidCoder-Beta\ but it's actually writing somewhere else. However when I try to open an explorer window it goes to the first location (where the data isn't). How can I get the actual write location from inside the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP apps store their appdata in a subfolder located in

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages

This should be where your app is now storing its data, under a subfolder that is most likely named with a random set of characters. To find out which random folder your app is, look in the **Packaging** section of the application manifest. (Package.AppXManifest). The "Package Family Name" should be part of the name of your app's appdata folder, as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFFLf.png). Once you've found the folder, local data is stored under the subfolder LocalState, roaming data under the folder RoamingState.

Comment: One wrinkle I've found with this is that they *will* use the real AppData folder if it already exists and there are files there. So in my case I needed to check the Local\Packages folder, then fall back to the real AppData folder if it wasn't there.